# Python modify .bak file

Tags: json, python-2.7

How can I use python (2.7) to elegantly read and modify a .bak?

The file contains a list of objects and I only know how to do this by converting it into a text file first. Can I get it in JSON format?

```
 [{'color':'green', 'shape':'square'},{'color':'red', 'shape':'circle'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is JSON: an array of two dictionaries/objects, both of them having the color and shape attributes, both strings.

You may wish to use the library presented at [JSON (Python 2.6 or newer)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for the purpose of encoding and decoding JSON. I suppose you know how to work with files (I don't, frankly)